# Spring config server return null for properties in client application

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud-config

Spring config server work properly and return below response for URL:- `http://localhost:8888/limits-service/default`

```
{
    "name": "limits-service",
    "profiles": [
        "default"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": "08da3c031373162bca129f75a914f8f4a5ccee8f",
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "https://github.com/miccloudtest/miccloudtest/limits-service.properties",
            "source": {
                "limits-service.minimum": "1099999",
                "limits-service.maximum": "1008888"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "https://github.com/miccloudtest/miccloudtest/application.properties",
            "source": {
                "spring.application.name": "spring-client-config-server",
                "server.port": "8888",
                "spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri": "https://github.com/miccloudtest/miccloudtest"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But my client application limits-service return below response for URL:-`http://localhost:8080/limits`

```
{
    "maximum": null,
    "minimum": null
}
```

My whole code uploaded to Git repository to below location

[Client Application](https://github.com/miccloudtest/miccloudtest/blob/master/limit%20service.tar.gz) 
[Config Server Application](https://github.com/miccloudtest/miccloudtest/blob/master/msspring-config-server.tar.gz)

Please help me so that I continue my spring cloud learning.Thanks in advance.

Client application name is **limit-service**.

Config server application name is **client config server**.

Git resource file name is `limits-servive.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be in the application if you say that a request to `http://localhost:8888/limits-service/default` completes well.

I suggest you to run the app with **--debug** option and it will print a lot about the startup. Might help

Comment: Thanks Mark for your suggestion,I have tried with Debug option but did not find any root cause.Will try more on it.

Comment: I don't see anything inusual

Answer (score 0):

Your file name is having typo for `limits-service.properties`.